# Is there ever a case for internally hosting public artifacts on a private Maven repository?

Tags: java, maven

There are times when a given Java third party is not in central Maven, possibly because it is very old (e.g., pre-dates Maven) or because - for whatever reason - it has never been uploaded there.  One solution is to create a local repo (local Nexus server) for these assets.  However, I am wondering how common this is and whether this is just plain wrong.  Is there ever a case where one would want to or *should* do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is one common use case for a Maven Repository Manager such as Nexus (eg. Oracle JDBC drivers comes to mind).

There are many more use cases why it's considered a [best practice](https://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html) to always use a Maven Repository Manager for any significant usage of Maven artifacts.

Comment: Thank you, I completely understand the case where a company like Oracle or whomever refuses to publish their artifacts to Central.  But suppose I have an old version of, say, log4j.  Or maybe something that is open source but is just not in Central yet.  Is it ever correct to host things locally in a Nexus or is the answer to always upload those things to Central?  Thanks, your answer is very much on the helpful track...

Comment: And just to be clear, I also understand the benefits of having a local repository manager, to keep local copies of assets.  But I'm mostly interested in the case where an open (or semi-open) asset is NOT in central maven.  I was just curious how common that was -- certainly, the vendor case like Oracle is a good example.  Are there others?

Comment: If you want to make a software which you like to offer other branches of the company or other teams in your company but don't want to make it open source (via Central)...Furthermore improving speed of builds cause it's cached in your internal network insted of alway accessing external network...Artifact procurment (control what kind of artifact you or devs are using for example having the right licenses security issues etc.).No need to define repositories in pom files. Deploy internal build artifacts from your CI into repository manager and deploy on different system...